# Unable to use Variable in XPath in Eclipse - Selenium

Tags: eclipse, variables, xpath, selenium

I need to pass values from excel sheet ( stored in variable api ) to XPATH in eclipse (java - Selenium).

I tried several options but none works. Please guide.

Here is my line of code.

```
String appcode = //input[contains(@id,'app') and contains(@type,'text') and ancestor::div[contains(@id, '+api+')]]
```

When i hardcode the value of api as below it works.

```
String appcode="//input[contains(@id,'app') and contains(@type,'text') and ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'setmember')]]";
```

Isnt it this easy?

Appreciate your help

pk

Answer (score 3):

you probably did not end the String constructor properly. Try this:

```
String appcode = "//input[contains(@id,'app') and contains(@type,'text') and ancestor::div[contains(@id, '" +api+" ')]]";
```

My assumption is, that `api` variable is type `String`

Comment: Also, a quick start guide (a first link from Google) on String concatenation so you know what's happening: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=217

Answer (score 0):

you can use **\"** so you would have something like

```
String appcode ="//input[contains(@id,\" "+[VARIABLE]+ " \")[..] ";
```