# how to pass value from valraible in to xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have xpath :
 ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed_ctl65_chkSelect']"

I have value in variable  v = 70,

i want to change xpath = ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed_ctlv_chkSelect']"

I am using  xpath 1.0, not  xpath 2.0

Can any one please help me

Comment: Instead of   "65"  in xpath i want to pass value from variable,  pls help me

Comment: What selenium language bindings are u using?

Comment: I am using java in selenium webdriver

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274342/unable-to-use-variable-in-xpath-in-eclipse-selenium, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196567/adding-java-variable-to-xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the below code will work by passing the value v at runtime

```
public void selectChk(String v) throws Exception {
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//* [@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed_ctl"+v+"_chkSelect']"))
            .click();
} catch (AssertionError Ae) {
    Ae.printStackTrace();
}
}
```