# Regular expression in xpath using selenium

Tags: selenium

My xpath =

> ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed']/tbody/tr[67]]/td[1]/strong"

where value 67  keeps on changing. How can i use Regular expression so that i can read the value of this element?

Please Need help,Thanks

Comment: Can any one please help me,

Comment: So your problem is that you never know which table row your data is in? Sometimes roe 67, sometimes elsewhere? I can't see how a RegEx could help you with that. Is there anything constant about the element you try to locate?

Comment: Hi,  the whole xpath is constant,  except the number 67,  if i can use regular expression , for 67 , than i can read the value .

Comment: Actually element text field value =   "Total :67"    so the xpath is  ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed']/tbody/tr[67]]/td[1]/strong"

Comment: the total value is changing depends on the number of values in the table, irrespective of that i want to read the value

Comment: To clarify my question the element is   "Total :67"   its  xpath is ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed']/tbody/tr[67]]/td[1]/strong".

Comment: Ok, so the number of rows in the table is dynamic. RegEx (like a wildcard) doesn't help because you don't want to find the first element that matches but retrieve the value of the last row, right? So, you should retrieve the number of rows from the text field which says _value = "Total :67_ Can you edit your question and post the HTML code of that text field?

Comment: There are currently 67 rows , which i snot constant, it may change ,  but i would like to read the value even though the no of rows changes .  pls need help

Comment: I am attaching the screenshot where it shows the value

Comment: sorry i could not attach the screenshot , not showing any option to attach

Comment: Screenshots don't help. Please paste the snippet of HTML code (as edit to your question, not as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know your HTML, it's not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. But if you say you want to find row #67 and the total number is also 67, then I assume you are trying to find the **last** row in the table!?

If this is case, instead of stating `tr[67]`, you should simply use `tr[last()]`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Thanks once again

Comment: BTW, if you don't mind accepting my answer, I would appreciate it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The below link is similar one as discussed,

[how to pass value from valraible in to xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019451/how-to-pass-value-from-valraible-in-to-xpath)

```
public void selectTableRow(String v) throws Exception {
try {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed']/tbody/tr["+v+"]]/td[1]/strong".click();
 }
 catch (AssertionError Ae)
{
 Ae.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is xpath : ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_frmClear_dgCashed']/tbody/tr[67]]/td[1]/strong"       this  value  67  is dynamic , i want to have regular expressioon so that i can read the value from xpath  which i can use it ....so i need your help